# when pressing on start button , background color of the browser window is not getting changed using html,CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-10, atom-editor

When I press start button the background color of browser window should change . First it should turn to red for 30 seconds then to yellow for 5 seconds and then to green for 30 seconds.It should happen atleast once.
//Below is HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Traffic Light</h1>
<div>
<button id="btn1">Start</button>
</div>
</body>
<script src="TrafficLightJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

//Below is Javascript file:

```
const colors=["red","yellow","green"];
const btn=document.getElementById("btn");
//const color=document.querySelector(".color");
btn.addEventListener("click",function()){
setInterval(function())  {
document.body.style.background=colors[0];
},30000);
setInterval(function())  {
document.body.style.background=colors[1];
},5000);
setInterval((function()) {
document.body.style.background=colors[2];
},30000);
```

}

//CSS File is below:

```
.red
{
background-color:red;
}
.yellow
{
background-color:yellow;
}
.green
{
background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: The color should be yellow instead of orange. CSS file is following: .red
{
background-color:red;
}
.yellow
{
background-color:yellow;
}
.green
{
  background-color:green;
}

Comment: Use your browser's devtools inspect facility and look at the console to see what syntax errors there might be. Then if you still have problems, insert some console.log calls into your code so you can track exactly what is happening. And read up about how to set styles. MDN is a reliable source for such info.

Comment: This maybe give you some idea. https://codepen.io/navab/pen/oNEKJyo

Comment: Thanks MORÈ, A Hawort  for helping. Navab Rahimi , your code worked and solved my issuse.Thanks Navab Rahimi